# Self join to find referral clients met

Tags: self, self-join

I have a visits table, where a RM Visits a PAN and that pan can refer another pan to meet.

So in the table we have. RM, Visit Date, PAN(To whom RM Met), Referred PAN. I need to check the count of referred pan met by that RM within a particular date range. Here i have a issue were i need to put a condition that the referral PAN was met after the original visit date wherein the pan was referred, because we cant have a visit before the PAN was even referred.

```
SELECT COUNT(PAN_NO) Met
FROM DIM_RM_VISITS
WHERE VISIT_DATE BETWEEN '01-FEB-2016' AND '01-MAR-2016'
AND PAN_NO IN 
(
   SELECT REFFERAL_CLIENT_NAME FROM DIM_RM_VISITS
   WHERE VISIT_DATE BETWEEN '01-FEB-2016' AND '01-MAR-2016'
)
AND RM_CODE = '100540';
```

Comment: self? self-join? you mean SQL?

Comment: can you post your desired result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(PAN_NO) Met FROM DIM_RM_VISITS v WHERE VISIT_DATE BETWEEN '01-FEB-2016' AND '01-MAR-2016' AND PAN_NO IN ( SELECT REFFERAL_CLIENT_NAME FROM DIM_RM_VISITS rv WHERE VISIT_DATE BETWEEN '01-FEB-2016' AND '01-MAR-2016' AND v.VISIT_DATE <= rv.VISIT_DATE ) AND RM_CODE = '100540';
```

Just alias the tables and refer to the main table's visit column in the sub-select to further filter data.